# The type Play must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)

Tags: android, imagebutton

```
    package com.example.applecounter;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.R.integer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.transition.Fade;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

//Here start my code //

public class Play extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    int counter=0;
    private MediaPlayer mplayer;
    private TextView txt;
    private static final int[] idArray = { R.id.imageButton1, R.id.imageButton2 };
    private ImageButton[] bt = new ImageButton[10];
    // This is oncreate() which works fine but the code for make an ImageButton array is not working  and got the error.
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);

        for (int i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
            final int b = i;
            bt[b] = (ImageButton) findViewById(idArray[b]);
            bt[b].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When I import the ViewOnClickListener, so I get the error which you will find below.
Here you have my code and I got the error

> The type Play must implement the inherited abstract method
>   View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
public class Play extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

You need to override

```
@Override
public void onClick(View V)
{

}
```

Since you have a annonymous inner class you don't require `implements OnClickListener`

Comment: you do not never know :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing your onClick method -inside- the onCreate,

1) Inside your onCreate state your `btn_whatEver.setOnClickListener(this);`

2) override `public void onClick(View V)` -outside- your onCreate method and call your various buttons using Switch.